# Turing machine for palindrome

Tags: turing-machines

Describe TM with one tape and two tape, which decide language сonsisting of palindrome (words have only '1' and '0' symbols). Estimate time of work each TM.

Comment: This isn't a question. It appears to be a dump of a homework assignment. Good luck with doing it.

Comment: More constructively: questions such as your own which seem to be requests for others to do their homework for them tend to be negatively received on Stack Overflow. On the other hand, if you can describe what you have tried and where you are stuck and ask for a hint rather than a full solution, you are likely to get some useful help. Finally, note that questions regarding Turing Machines are more likely to be on topic in the theoretical computer science stack exchange: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One tape:

Read first symbol and move to state A if 0 or state B if 1. Replace with a blank. Move right to the end of the tape (first blank symbol). Move left one symbol. If this symbol is a 0 and you are in state A, or if it is 1 and you are in state B, make it a blank and return all the way to the left until you find a blank symbol, and then move one right. Otherwise, the word is not a palindrome and you halt-reject. Continue in this manner until you halt-reject or all symbols on the tape have been replaced with blanks, in which case you halt-accept. This will take roughly (n+1) + n + ... + 1 ~ O(n^2) moves.

Two tapes:

Move the tape head of the input tape to the end, and then read backwards to the start of the input tape. As you go, write the tape symbols in order on the second tape so that you end up with the reverse of the input tape on the second tape. Reset both tape heads, and then move each to the end of the tape, at each step comparing the symbols each head is pointing to. If you find a position where the symbols are different, the input is not a palindrome and you halt-reject. If you get to the end (first blank symbol on the end) without finding a mismatch then it is a palindrome and you halt-accept.